# sql identity issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have column id which has identity column

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(id int primary key identity(1,1),
name varchar(255));
```

Problem is that after 10 its gives value 111 then 112
why it is not giving 11

Comment: that depends what you do to it. rollback any transactions? delete any records?

Comment: Identity increments include deleted records. So if you added 100 records to this table, then deleted them, the next insert would have an ID of 101. You can reset it with DBCC CHECKIDENT.

Comment: no i   am just inserting one column after 10 it is giving 111 why?

Comment: post the entire code to reproduce your problem

Comment: [Stop making assumptions about `IDENTITY`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity), stop worrying about gaps - they are really **NOT** a problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the cause, you can reset your identity column using the DBCC CHECKIDENT command.

It accepts parameters to allow you to reset the value to whatever you desire. For example this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TableNameHere]', RESEED, 11)
```

Will reset the column to 11 - you can substitute whatever number is required as the final parameter.

Using `TRUNCATE TABLE` will also reset any identity columns - but it will also delete all your data, obviously. Using `DELETE` will remove data, but it does not change identity values.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you are inserting the data into it. If it's simple `INSERT INTO` and nothing else around it, it's weird.

Maybe it's that issue with MSSQL 2012 server? There is a know bug about identity jump when server restarts.

More information http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is

Comment: Wow, 20 year was enough for MS to follow Oracle and recommends using sequence instead of identity. How many times I've heard that identity is much better and sequence is unnecessary.

Comment: It is not a bug, it is by design, to make it efficient. The server allocates a block of identity numbers in advance (cache them) instead of allocating them one by one. Sequence object allows to explicitly turn the cache on or off.

Comment: Someone calls that as a feature, someone as a bug :-), yes I've read the bug report https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity